# How to get assembly from exe?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I used some methods like `assembly.load` and `assembly.loadfrom` and `assembly.loadfile` but when I print that assembly it gives output like

```
"exename",version="1.0.0.0",culture="neural",publickeytoken=null
```

How to I get assemblies from `exe`?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to get all referenced assemblies from an exe file, you can try it like this:

```
  System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(EXEPATH).GetReferencedAssemblies();
```

Where EXEPATH is of course the absolute path to the .exe file

Comment: thanks for your reply. But how to I get that assembly value in object. i.e. Assembly assembly =System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\sample.exe").GetReferencedAssemblies(); shows error. the error is "cannot implicitly convert type System.Reflection.Assembly[] to System.Reflection.Assembly" like this. How to I get that assemblies values? @Keran

Comment: GetReferencedAssemblies () returns an array of assemblies (multiple objects). So you need to have: Assembly [] assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile (@"C:\Sample.exe").GetReferencedAssemblies ();  and then you search for the assembly you want. If you want only the first assembly, you can use GetReferemcedAssemblies ().FirstOrDefault ();

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried your method. but still shows error. I don't know why. It shows the following error: "cannot implicitly convert type System.Reflection.AssemblyName to System.Reflection.Assembly[]" @Keran

Comment: If you use GetReferencedAssemblies().FirstOrDefault () you will receive one object (AssemblyName). If you use only GetReferencedAssemblies() you will receive an array (AssemblyName[])